# Deleting the definite article 'the' before ordinal numbers

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say "Amundsen's expedition was first to reach the South Pole"?

Comment: Depends on the context.  If you preface with "There were several expeditions simultaneously attempting to reach the pole" then "the" should probably be omitted.  If not, not.

Answer (score 6):

Although the [corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20first%20to%2Cwas%20the%20first%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20first%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20the%20first%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows the expression *was the first to* as **more** common, it seems *was first to* is [common enough](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was%20first%20to%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl):

[image]

The ordinal *first* determines sufficient **definiteness**, so the extra determiner is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: It's typical to use "the" when there is no order/competition.  But if there were several "contestants" then "the" may be omitted - Jack was first to reach the barber pole, Bill was second.  I'm vaguely recalling that this somehow gets tied up in some cardinal/ordinal distinction, or some such.

Comment: The most baffling thing about this sentence is that it was written without a previous context.